# How to copy Grails 2 plugin resources to the Grails app?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-2.4, gant

I'm writing a custom Grails 2 plugin to modularize my Grails applications. In the plugin I'm planning to define basic GSPs that can be overridden by the application that will utilize the plugin. I'm thinking of writing a Grails command script that copies those GSPs into the `grails-app` directory of the app the plugin is installed in. If in the plugin, I put those GSPs in `grails-app/views`, how do I refer to the actual Grails app directory in the Grails command script, which is also `grails-app/views`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is almost the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877545/404604). The built-in properties `basedir` and `<plugin_name>PluginBaseDir` differentiate the target app and the plugin directories.